# TYPO3 and sitemap_generator

Tags: typo3, sitemap

I use TYPO3 7.6.10 and sitemap_generator 1.0

I see the sitemap.xml and it generates the map but there are not the categories and tags like "categoy/nameofcategory".
How can I solve it?

The code in template is:

```
plugin.tx_sitemapgenerator {
    urlEntries {
        pages = 1
        pages {
            rootPageId = 1
            allowedDoktypes = 1
            additionalWhere = doktype!=6
        }
    }
}

plugin.tx_sitemapgenerator {
    urlEntries {
        news = 1
        news {
            active = 1
            table = tx_news_domain_model_news
            additionalWhere = pid!=0
            orderBy = title DESC
            limit = 0,1000
            lastmod = tstamp
            url = TEXT
            url {
                typolink.parameter = 161
                typolink.additionalParams = &tx_news_pi1[controller]=News&tx_news_pi1[action]=detail&tx_news_pi1[news]={field:uid}
                typolink.additionalParams.insertData = 1
                typolink.useCacheHash = 1
                typolink.returnLast = url
                typolink.forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A sitemap for google doesn't contain such stuff as tags and description, so there is no need for the extension to deliver that stuff. Check the specs of creating a sitemap here. [Google build a sitemap](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en#sitemapformat)